# How to make a cyclic reset of a byte through zero by sum?

Tags: python, byte

I created bytes. Also I try to make addition of bytes. But I am getting an error

*ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)*

Instead of an error, I expect a loop, for example 255+2 = 1. How can I do it like in C?

```
bytes_ = bytearray([0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF])  
bytes_[0] = bytes_[0] + 1
bytes_[1] = bytes_[1] + 2
bytes_[2] = bytes_[2] + 3
print(bytes_)
```

Comment: `bytes_[0] = (bytes_[0] + 1) % 256` or `bytes_[0] = (bytes_[0] + 1) & 0xFF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually adding relies on bitwise addition of the bits using the carry flag in a register of the CPU. The excessive bits are skipped (the value can be seen in the carry flag) say in an 8 bit register, so only the numbers 0 to 255 are represented.  See [here](https://iq.opengenus.org/addition-using-bitwise-operations/) for some internals.

Python bytes don't work like a CPU register.

This is what at least "cyles" through a byte:

```
byte=0xF9
for i in range(10):
  byte = (byte+1) & 255
  print(byte)
```

You normally add, using integer arithmetics and cut off all excessive bits by using a bitwise AND: `& 255`.

Output:

```
250
251
252
253
254
255
0
1
2
3
```

Your example modified:

```
bytes_ = bytearray([0xF9])
for i in range(10):
  bytes_[0] = (bytes_[0] + 1) & 255
  print(bytes_[0])
```

Gives the same output.

Comment: What about bit shift? 
bytes_[0] = bytes_[0] << 2;

Comment: bit shifting is multiplication (left shift) or division (right shift) by 2. You

Comment: You must shift away the 9th bit if it exists (i.e. if result is larger 255), not the first: if bytes > 255: bytes = bytes - bytes >>8. It is easier to mask all 8 bits with & 255. This always works, despite of the result, and is faster.

Comment: It works! Thank you! 
... bytes_[0] = (bytes_[0] << 5) & 255
... bytes_[0] = (bytes_[0] + 5) & 255